# Add a character every -1 of the index in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have this code, I want to add a "(" every -1 of the index

```
import string
index = 0
import re
lengthstr = 0 

def PAR():
global index
global lengthstr
exp = input("Input: ")
lengthstr = len(exp)
while index < len(exp):
    index = exp.find("L", index)
    if index == -1:
        break
    print("found at", index)
    index += 1
    par = '('
    new = par + exp[:index] + exp[index:]
    print(new)
```

For example, when I type in Lm.Lm output would be (Lm.(Lm

Comment: print 'Lm.Lm'.replace('L','(L') ?

Answer (score 1):

use the str.replace() method!

```
def par():
    return input('Input: ').replace('L', '(L')

>>> par()
Input: Lm.Lm.
'(Lm.(Lm.'
```